# Access host name inside config AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Because you cant access services inside `.config` how would I get access to properties like `$host` normally found in `$locationService` ?

I am trying to load partials based on current subdomain. *All subdomains point to base host doc root.*

When viewing:

```
example.com
```

templateUrl would be:

```
views/home.html
```

When viewing:

```
spicy.example.com
```

templateUrl would be:

```
views/spicy/home.html
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the app.run method, you can use $routeChangeStart event to intercept just before route is executed. In your .config, specify the templateURL as the file of the template itself (e.g home.html, without /views)

```
app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'home.html',
        controller: 'HomeCtrl'
      });
    ...
});
```

and then you can add the following code in the .run:

```
app.run(function ($rootScope,$location){
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart',function(event,next,current){
        next.templateUrl = "views/"+$location.host()+"/"+next.templateUrl;
    });
});
```

and it will access home.html under views/<host>/home.html

Plunker example: http://embed.plnkr.co/82qV7uCZOBgZxjahhlU3/
Please note I use _ instead of / to simulate directory where the file resides based on the hostname. Plunker doesn't like / in the filename (refused to save the file although I was able to run it)

Comment: +1 This looks like exactly what im looking for! Getting an error however: templateUrl is undefined ? Also, it seems like my digest is stuck in a loop when I tail my console.log(). Could you provide a plunker/fiddle?

Comment: I missed 'next' before templateUrl as next has all the properties. I have fixed the code above. You just need to access next object and manipulate it as required

Comment: Mabye it would be helpful to make a plunker/fiddle? I'm stuck in a loop where I keep reloading all of my app dependencies.

Comment: Check this: http://embed.plnkr.co/82qV7uCZOBgZxjahhlU3/ - this is simple approach. Some limitation in plnkr so I cannot use / for directories - instead i use _ - see the js code for comments. Your implementation may be more complex than this so not sure what your digest issue is.

Answer (score 0):

You can access $$host in config. You just can't use $location. Instead use $urlRouterProvider. However, $urlRouterProvider populates $location as empty for some reason, so you can also use pure javascript window to get the url host if you are changing your config env based on different url hosts.

E.g.

```
function config($urlRouterProvider) {
  if ($urlRouterProvider._router.locationService.$location)
    console.log(console.log($urlRouterProvider._router.locationService.$location.$$host))
  else
    console.log(window.location.host)
}
```